# How can I rewrite the script for Dates?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I query data for each month, here's an example for JANUARY:

```
SELECT * FROM REPORT
WHERE OPENED_DATE < '31 JANUARY 2021' AND CLOSED_DATE >= '01 JANUARY 2021'
```

And I have to do it for each month and combine results using `UNION ALL`.

Is there a way to do this without using `UNION ALL` and to query Data only for last 12 months?

I've tried this, but it does not seem to be correct:

```
SELECT * FROM REPORT
WHERE OPENED_DATE <= LAST_DAY(OPENED_DATE) 
AND CLOSED_DATE >= TRUNC(LAST_DAY(CLOSED_DATE)-1, 'MM')
```

I need to divide and group data for each month without using `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a calendar that contains all months in a year. For sysdate's year, that would be

```
SQL> with
  2  calendar as
  3    (select add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy'), level - 1) datum
  4     from dual
  5     connect by level <= 12
  6    )
  7  select * from calendar;

DATUM
-----------
01-JAN-2021
01-FEB-2021
01-MAR-2021
01-APR-2021
01-MAY-2021
01-JUN-2021
01-JUL-2021
01-AUG-2021
01-SEP-2021
01-OCT-2021
01-NOV-2021
01-DEC-2021

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Now join the `calendar` with `report`:

```
with 
calendar as
  (select add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy'), level - 1) datum
   from dual
   connect by level <= 12
  )
select to_char(c.datum, 'Month') month,
  r.*
from calendar c join report r on r.opened_date between c.datum and last_day(c.datum)
order by c.datum;
```

---

**[EDIT]**

If calendar has to span more than current year, then fix its query. For example, you could find `MIN(year from opened_date)` and create months since that year to current year; something like this:

```
SQL> select * from report;

        ID OPENED_DATE
---------- -----------
         1 12-MAR-2019       --> min(year) = 2019
         2 13-AUG-2020

SQL> with
  2  start_year as
  3    (select min(extract (year from opened_date)) start_year
  4     from report
  5    ),
  6  calendar as
  7    (select add_months(to_date(start_year, 'yyyy'), level - 1) datum
  8     from start_year
  9     connect by level <= (extract(year from sysdate) - start_year) * 12 + 1
 10    )
 11  select * from calendar;

DATUM
-----------
01-DEC-2019
01-JAN-2020
01-FEB-2020
01-MAR-2020
01-APR-2020
<snip>
01-NOV-2021
01-DEC-2021

25 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you. But your script doesn't show correct results. I need to choose open reports. For instance, in January, they could be opened before January (OPENED_DATE <= '31 JANUARY 2021') and be closed after January (CLOSED_DATE >= '01 JANUARY 2021'). THis means they were open at the month of January. How can I do this?

Your script only filters reports that were open in 2021, but in my case they could have been opened in 2019 and 2020.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, *calendar* needs to have not only current year, but *many years*. If that's so, modify its query. See edited answer.